# R: How to convert long number to string to save precision

Tags: r, precision, tostring, long-integer

I have a problem to convert a long number to a string in R. How to easily convert a number to string to preserve precision? A have a simple example below.

```
a = -8664354335142704128
toString(a)

[1] "-8664354335142704128"

b = -8664354335142703762
toString(b)

[1] "-8664354335142704128"

a == b

[1] TRUE
```

I expected `toString(a)` == `toString(b)`, but I got different values. I suppose `toString()` converts the number to float or something like that before converting to string.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

```
> -8664354335142704128 == -8664354335142703762

[1] TRUE

> along = bit64::as.integer64(-8664354335142704128)
> blong = bit64::as.integer64(-8664354335142703762)
> along == blong

[1] TRUE

> blong

integer64
[1] -8664354335142704128
```

I also tried:

```
> as.character(blong)

[1] "-8664354335142704128"

> sprintf("%f", -8664354335142703762)

[1] "-8664354335142704128.000000"

> sprintf("%f", blong)

[1] "-0.000000"
```

**Edit 2:**

My question first was, if I can convert a long number to string without loss. Then I realized, in R is impossible to get the real value of a long number passed into a function, because R automatically read the value with the loss.

For example, I have the function:

```
> my_function <- function(long_number){
+ string_number <- toString(long_number)
+ print(string_number)
+ }
```

If someone used it and passed a long number, I am not able to get the information, which number was passed exactly.

```
> my_function(-8664354335142703762)
[1] "-8664354335142704128"
```

For example, if I read some numbers from a file, it is easy. But it is not my case. I just need to use something that some user passed.

I am not R expert, so I just was curious why in another language it works and in R not. For example in Python:

```
>>> def my_function(long_number):
...     string_number = str(long_number)
...     print(string_number)
... 
>>> my_function(-8664354335142703762)
-8664354335142703762
```

Now I know, the problem is how R reads and stores numbers. Every language can do it differently. I have to change the way how to pass numbers to R function, and it solves my problem.

**So the correct answer to my question is:**

*""I suppose toString() converts the number to float", nope, you did it yourself (even if unintentionally)."* - Nope, R did it itself, that is the way how R reads numbers.

So I marked r2evans answer as the best answer because this user helped me to find the right solution. Thank you!

Comment: You could store `a` and `b` as `bit64::as.integer64()` and then `a != b` correctly returns `FALSE`.

Comment: if you really want a string, there's always `as.character` or `sprintf`, but I think @Mako212's is a better solution.

Comment: Haven't you already lost the precision as soon as you do `a = -8664354335142704128`? The data has to be read in from the source as a 64-bit int I think.

Comment: I meant TRUE in my first

Comment: Hi @Mako212 I tried your suggested solution, but it has the same effect. I edited my question to show the results.

Comment: Hi @r2evans I also tried your suggested solution...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bottom line up front, you must (in this case) read in your large numbers as string before converting to 64-bit integers:

```r
bit64::as.integer64("-8664354335142704128") == bit64::as.integer64("-8664354335142703762")
# [1] FALSE
```

Some points about what you've tried:

- *"I suppose toString() converts the number to float"*, nope, you did it yourself (even if unintentionally). In R, when creating a number, `5` is a float and `5L` is an integer. Even if you had tried to create it as an integer, it would have complained and lost precision anyway:

  ```
  class(5)
  # [1] "numeric"
  class(5L)
  # [1] "integer"
  class(-8664354335142703762)
  # [1] "numeric"
  class(-8664354335142703762L)
  # Warning: non-integer value 8664354335142703762L qualified with L; using numeric value
  # [1] "numeric"
  ```
- more appropriately, when you type it in as a number and *then* try to convert it, R processes the inside of the parentheses first. That is, with

  ```
  bit64::as.integer64(-8664354335142704128)
  ```

  R first has to parse and "understand" everything inside the parentheses before it can be passed to the function. (This is typically a compiler/language-parsing thing, not just an R thing.) In this case, it sees that it appears to be a (large) negative float, so it creates a class `numeric` (float). Only *then* does it send this `numeric` to the function, but by this point the precision has already been lost. Ergo the otherwise-illogical

  ```
  bit64::as.integer64(-8664354335142704128) == bit64::as.integer64(-8664354335142703762)
  # [1] TRUE
  ```

  In this case, it just *happens that the 64-bit version of that number is equal to what you intended.

  ```
  bit64::as.integer64(-8664254335142704128)  # ends in 4128
  # integer64
  # [1] -8664254335142704128                 # ends in 4128, yay! (coincidence?)
  ```

  If you subtract one, it results in the same effective `integer64`:

  ```
  bit64::as.integer64(-8664354335142704127)  # ends in 4127
  # integer64
  # [1] -8664354335142704128                 # ends in 4128 ?
  ```

  This continues for quite a while, until it finally shifts to the next rounding point

  ```
  bit64::as.integer64(-8664254335142703617)
  # integer64
  # [1] -8664254335142704128
  bit64::as.integer64(-8664254335142703616)
  # integer64
  # [1] -8664254335142703104
  ```

  It is unlikely to be coincidence that the difference is 1024, or 2^10. I haven't fished yet, but I'm guessing there's something meaningful about this with respect to floating point precision in 32-bit land.
- fortunately, `bit64::as.integer64` has several S3 methods, useful for converting different formats/classes to a `integer64`

  ```
  library(bit64)
  methods(as.integer64)
  # [1] as.integer64.character as.integer64.double    as.integer64.factor   
  # [4] as.integer64.integer   as.integer64.integer64 as.integer64.logical  
  # [7] as.integer64.NULL
  ```

  So, `bit64::as.integer64.character` can be useful, since precision is *not* lost when you type it or read it in as a string:

  ```
  bit64::as.integer64("-8664354335142704128")
  # integer64
  # [1] -8664354335142704128
  bit64::as.integer64("-8664354335142704128") == bit64::as.integer64("-8664354335142703762")
  # [1] FALSE
  ```
- FYI, your number is already near the 64-bit boundary:

  ```
  -.Machine$integer.max
  # [1] -2147483647
  -(2^31-1)
  # [1] -2147483647
  log(8664354335142704128, 2)
  # [1] 62.9098
  -2^63 # the approximate +/- range of 64-bit integers
  # [1] -9.223372e+18
  -8664354335142704128
  # [1] -8.664354e+18
  ```

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for the comprehensive answer. But my problem is, that I can't read the number from a file, I got it for example as an argument of a function. So I realized, that the number -8664354335142703762 itself can't be pass to function without loss in R neither convert to string... Am I right? FYI: My number which I want to convert is -8664354335142703762 not -8664354335142704128. I know that the number -8664354335142704128 is near the 64-bit boundary. :)

Comment: Your problem then is that function, not any of this, since it is likely that the precision is then lost well before the other function returns it. Please edit your question with enough context so we can know what you code you are using that produces this output that you cannot capture as a string.

Comment: I already know the problem is the function, but I think the question is still relevant and I find the answer (also thanks to your answer) - there is no way to pass the real value of the long number (for example -8664354335142703762) into R function as a number without loss. Only with a long number in string, I can work in R. So your answer will be correct if I already have the string representation of the number. But that is what I don't have. Why I would put the string number to toString function if I have already had the string? :)

Comment: Nobody can help with a process you have not shared. The problem is with that R function (whether its return value or what it prints to the console), so please share that R function. If it is returning a `numeric`, then the problem is entirely in that function and nothing you can do can fix it. If it is printing something to the console, you can use `capture.output` and figure out how to parse it (thereby `character`). Otherwise, the question here is becoming moot: you ask about how to unbreak something after it is already irreversibly altered.

Comment: The question is relevant to somebody who either (1) has control over entering the numbers, or (2) has the ability to read them in as strings. Your last comment suggests you are neither, unfortunately.